# Rails controller add parameters on view load

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view with some required parameters. If these parameters are not provided, I would like the controller to add the parameters (with value empty string), so that users can add those values in the url (rather than guessing what the parameter keys are).

Example:
I want to visit: `localhost:3000/page/index`
I require parameters 'a', b', 'c' to be filled out to render this page

On load of this view, the controller will append the url to the following: `localhost:3000/page/index?a=&b=&c=`  if these parameters are not provided.

Essentially, I'd just like to add parameters to the url through the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can just redirect to the same page with any query params you want.

```
# in index action:
hash = {a: '', b: '', c: ''}    
return redirect_to "/page/index?#{hash.to_query}"
```

Just wrap this in some if statement to make sure these keys are not in the params already, or you would end up in an infinite redirect loop.